# Trigger next function on complete of first

Tags: javascript, function, triggers, callback

I have the following javascript geotagging script:

```
window.onload = function(){
var x=document.getElementById("output");
getLocation();
function getLocation()
{
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(reverseGeoLookup);
}
else
{
   x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function reverseGeoLookup(position) {
console.log(position);
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
 req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode    /json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(req.readyState == 4) {
      var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
      for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
          for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
              var component = result[i].address_components[j]
              //console.log(component.long_name);
              if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                var out = document.getElementById('output');
                out.value = component.long_name;
                return false;
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
 req.send()
 }

 setTimeout(function(){
 var str = document.getElementById('output').value ;
 var res = str.substring(0,3);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
 },1000);

 setTimeout(function(){

 window.location = 'mylocationurl' +      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML + '/' + 'index.html'
 },7000);
}
```

The code gets the user location, converts it to UK postcode and then redirects the user to the appropriate page. Currently the website is using `setTimeout` to tell the browser when to redirect.I would like to change this so as to make the events occur in order ie. find location then on complete shorten to first 3 digits then on complete of that redirect the visitor. Ideally i'd prefer to not use jQuery.
Can anybody help me?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Is this a really copy and past of your code? You have a syntax error here `window.location = mylocationurl' +      document.`

Comment: well the 'mylocationurl' is where i removed my actual url before posting.

Comment: all of the code functions as it should

Comment: remove the apostrophe after `mylocationurl` first...

Comment: as i said before, the code as it is functions correctly - i just want to change it to trigger one function after another, can anybody help with this?

Comment: may you can use `onreadystatechange` that call every time the request change status... http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp some doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry... only now i think to understand what you need to...

so... you need a callback function that fired at the end of your "getLocation" fucntion?

if the callback function is called when your XMLHttpRequest is loaded fully, so you need to insert the callback function inside onreadystatechange property of your XMLHttpRequest object.
An example:

```
function getLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(reverseGeoLookup(position,function(longName){
           console.log("function called, scope:",this,"args:",arguments);
           //callback function here
           //you can insert inside the callback the script inside "setTimeout"
           var res = longName.substring(0,3);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;

           //and after 7 sec. from the ajax request complete change page:
           setTimeout(function(){
                  window.location = 'mylocationurl' +      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML + '/' + 'index.html'
           },7000);
       }));
    }else{
       x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

window.onload = function(){
    var x=document.getElementById("output");
    getLocation();
}

function reverseGeoLookup(position,callback) {
    console.log(position);
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode    /json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(req.readyState == 4) {
          var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
          for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
              for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                  var component = result[i].address_components[j]
                  //console.log(component.long_name);
                  if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                    var out = document.getElementById('output');
                    out.value = component.long_name;

                    //insert here the callback if you need to wait fully request load
                    //note the argument inside of callback become longName.
                    callback(component.long_name);

                   return false;
                  }
              }
          }
       }

     }
     req.send();
 }
}
```

i hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

you can success this with callback functionality.

```
    function getLocation(param, callback) {
      getLocation stuff
      callback();
    }
```

Comment: I think that looks to be exactly what I need however I'm quite new to this kind of coding and I don't know how to implement it - can you help me further? Thank you very much for taking the time to help me!